# How to replace a File Path to a URL using Regex?

Tags: regex

I have an application running on Tomcat from my local machine. In the backend, I have a function that generates a PDF document and returns the absolute path.

Ex:
C:\Program Files\Enterprise\tomcat\webapps\my_app\reports\document.pdf

How could I use Regex to get in URL format?

Expected:
http://localhost:8080/my_app/reports/document.pdf

**Note**
The file path can be in Windows (`\`) or Linux (`/`)

Comment: First: replace all `\ ` with `/`. Next: replace `^.+?(?=\/my_app)` with `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Thx @MonkeyZeus! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus would appreciate!